# How do I find the merge that moved my changeset to another branch?

Tags: mercurial

I made a change a few months ago in a file in the default branch.  Today we discovered that change somehow got merged into another branch.  When I run `hg log` against that file, I'm only seeing the original changeset.  I'm not seeing how that changeset made it into the branch.

What revset query can I pass to `hg log` to trace a changeset as it gets merged between branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the changeset in question lives on a named branch, you can use `hg log -r 'descendants(<the_rev>) and branch(default)'`, and the first changeset shown should be the merge.

Comment: Your example shows all descendants on the given branch.  I only needed the first one, so I added the `first` function: `hg log -r 'first(descendants(<the_rev>) and branch(default))'`.