# Finding mercurial merges that modify a file

Tags: merge, mercurial

In Mercurial, how can I find merge changesets that modify a particular file?

The help for `log` and `diff` point out the quirks in dealing with merge changesets.

- They only show differences with respect to the first parent, not the second,
- and they do not treat the changeset as modifying a given file at all unless there are differences relative to *both* parents of the merge. (This is true whether one is using `modifies()` in the revset or passing the filename as another argument)

Is there a way to work around these quirks and find the changes?

Here's an example task: If I'm working on a tricky merge with conflicts, I may want to find all of the changesets on default that touched a file since my branch started, in order to verify and understand the content of the merge.  I'd like to be able to say

```
hg log -pr 'ancestor(mybranch,default)::default' path/to/myfile
```

and have it show me all of the relevant changes I'm merging in (since the common ancestor).  Because of those quirks, however, this misses anything coming in to default by a merge from another branch.

Comment: Here's a kind of workaround, although it gives extraneous detail if changes were done piecemeal or if work was done and undone: getting all the contentful changesets that feed into the part of default that hasn't been merged to my branch yet: `hg log -p -M -r  'ancestors(ancestor(mybranch,default)::default) and not ancestors(mybranch)' path/to/myfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to figure out how a changeset made it into a branch (or what changesets will come into a branch). A common question because merges in Mercurial are not the same as merges in non-distributed version control systems. In traditional VCS, like Subversion, a merge creates a new revision with all the changes from that incoming branch. Thus it is easy to find the merge where a file changed because it changed in the merge.

With Mercurial, however, merges don't behave this way: a merge is more like a labeling operation. Mercurial marks all the changes on the incoming branch as now belonging to the new branch.

Thus, when trying to figure out how a change to a file got into your branch, you have to ask two questions: what changeset introducted the change you're interested in and what merge brought that into your branch. You can use the `file()` revset query to answer the first question. Once you have that changeset, then you can use [this revset query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889485/how-do-i-find-the-merge-that-moved-my-changeset-to-another-branch) to find out what merge brought it into your branch: `'descendants(<the_rev>) and branch(<the branch>)`.

To find all the changesets that will be merged in *and* that modified a particular file:

```
 hg log -r "(::<incoming_branch> - ::<destination_branch>) and file('path/to/the/file')"
```

- `::<incoming_branch>` gets all the ancestors of the incoming branch
- `::<destination_branch>` gets all the ancestors of the destination branch
- `-` removes all the common changesets, leaving only those that haven't been merged
- `file('path/to/the/file')` filters the results to changesets that modifed that file

Comment: Merges aren’t just labeling operations. They introduce changes too. Before committing a merge, Mercurial lets you make edits to arbitrary files and add/remove files. Also, in any merge between two branches which modify the same file, oftentimes the modifications are combined together. Even if such a file can be automatically merged at the line-level by Mercurial itself, the results of the line-level merging have to be recorded and the resulting file will be different from both the first and second parents.

Answer (score 0):

> all of the changesets on default that touched a file

Excuse me, but isn't it just

```
hg log -r "branch(default) & file('path/to/myfile')"
```

or, if you want to have -M also

```
hg log -r "branch(default) & file('path/to/myfile') & !merge()"
```

Comment: No, I tested this just now with a merge changeset where `hg diff -r "p2(rev)" -r "rev" path/to/file` gives a diff for the file in question, but `hg log -r "rev & file('path/to/file')"` gives an empty result.  As I mentioned above, the merge is considered not to have modified the file unless there are differences relative to both parents.

Comment: (Regarding the example at the bottom of the question, you're right it was unclear why I was using the common ancestor.  I meant new changes being merged in from default since the branch started.  I'll make an edit of the phrase you quoted to clarify, but the larger question is how can I work around the strange way that mercurial defines whether a merge has modified a file.)